# Better alternative to locals() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was recently having somebody look over my code, and they said that my use of `locals()` wasn't the best, but they didnt say what could replace it. Here is a snippet:

```
if 'data' in locals():
    if data.index.freqstr == 'M':
        new_data = data
    elif data.index.freqstr in ['D','B']:
        new_data = data.resample('M').last().shift().dropna(how='all')
```

Why would my use of `locals()` be problematic in this case? and what would a better solution be?

Comment: Where is data defined?

Comment: Why do you need to check if `data` is in locals()? Typically it is pretty easy to know what local variables exist from how your code is written.

Comment: Your code just looks that `data` exist, but suppose data is None. Then doing `data.index.freqstr` will throw an exception.  I would put the code inside a `try except`, which will also capture the case where data doesn't exist

Comment: Without context, it's very difficult, maybe even impossible, to give good advice. Like, why wouldn't `data` be in `locals()` in the first place? Is it defined conditionally? If so, why? Please make a [mre] including at least where `data` is defined, but preferably an entire module, since this involves scope.